# Jquery Autocomplete doesn't load source from php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to load source for Jquery Ui Autocomplete from a php file that connects to database and gets results to an array, everything is working, but the Autocomplete widget doesn't load the provided array as source (i.e. when I type something in the autocomplete search box, request is made, response is received, but the results aren't shown in search box)

**My html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#skills" ).autocomplete({
        source: 'searchdata.php'
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="skills">Test: </label>
    <input id="skills">
</div>
```

---

**searchdata.php**

```
<?php 
require 'db.php';
header("Content-type: application/json");

$conn = new db();

$input = $_GET['term'];
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM galleries WHERE name LIKE ?");
$like = '%'.$input.'%';
$query->bind_param('s',$like);
$query->execute();
$result = $query->get_result();
while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $array[] = array (
        'label' => $row['name'],
        'value' => $row['id'],
    );
}
$conn->close();
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

---

[Response from searchdata.php + console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T02NW.png)

Comment: Looking at the image, there seem to be a red `.` character before the json data. That may be causing the problem.

Comment: Check if you're outputting before  `<?php` and remove unneeded or hidden characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### SOLVED

I've found it, thanks Karlo, didn't notice that little sneaky bastard :). It was indeed that "dot" (or, as I found out, U+FEFF), but not where I thought it was. A file with my database classes and config (which was required by searchdata.php) was saved as UTF8 with BOM, and it caused the problem. Saved it as UTF8 and the problem is now gone.